# Sharing data between VIewControllers - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scope, singleton

For any object created I generally use two two scopes 1) Singleton 2) {local scope}. I am looking for something in between.

Say I have one object that 5 view controllers are editing. I want to share an object between view controllers without having to pass it between view controllers. But it should not also live throughout application since once I am done editing the object i don't need it anymore.

I don't want to inherit all view controller from another class an create a variable there. Since view controller are reusable for different objects. I want to create an object that comes to life before launch of first view controller, lives throughout the scope of 5 view controllers and then dies after I have saved it someway. Is there anyways I could do this in iOS.

Comment: Why don't you want to pass the object between view controllers? That's the proper solution.

Comment: Because it was making view controllers closely coupled and difficult to understand the flow. Its like keeping local variables in first VC and then then passing it. If something edited by first VC was need by 4th one then i was just passing it through 4VC for no reason.

Comment: If passing data between controllers is making your code closely coupled then you are doing it incorrectly or you need to clarify your needs and what you are doing.

Comment: It is causing a lot of issues in deep linking. I don't want one view controller to be dependent on which one called it at any state of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mat said you can do is in that what. For me better is to create specific class for that that will do one particular job.

```
class EditingSession {
    class Factory {
        private static let session = EditingSession() //do it lazy
        static func create() -> EditingSession {
            return session
        }
    }

    func openSession() {

    }

    func endSession {

    }

    func getData () -> AnyObject {
        ...
    }
}
```

1. In editing session create private initializer. Factory should give the shared instance.
2. You can pass this class to your ViewControllers and manipulate with the data. You can inject it or just set as property in your VC or VM.
3. If you are done with editing you should end session and clear data or other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use your AppDelegate. Within it you can declare a global var than 2 functions, a first one to get the current value and another one to set the value.

It might give something like this:

```
// Get AppDelegate instance
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate;

// Use your getter to get the current value
var something = appDelegate.getYourStuff();

// Or use a setter to set it, a modifier to modify oit
appDelegate.setYourStuff(yourStuff);
appDelegate.modifiyYourStuffAttribute(newAttributeValue);
```

Don't realize if such a method is a bad practice or not, but it works for me.

Open to other suggestions!

Comment: Agree with Mat. You can define your object in AppDelegate, init in your first view controller and kill it when you finish editing in fifth view controller.